# Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, structure, dijkstra

I'm trying to implement dijkstra algorithm in C using double arrays with memory allocation (to solve it ina big big graph), but I can't make it run yet. My code doesn't turn any error, only that all answers are 0. Here it is, if you can i'm also looking for a way to do it without using multiple arrays (dimension matrix).

ADDED TEXTFILE, i keep getting `[warning] passing arg 3 of dijkstra from incompatible pointer type`

```
#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;
#define MAX 1000

void dijkstra(int n,int v,int cost[n][n],int dist[n]);

int main()
{
    int n,v, aux, aux1, aux2;

    int arc;
    FILE *archive;
    archive= fopen("TEXTFILE.txt","r");
    fscanf(archive,"%d %d",&n,&arc );
    printf("%d %d \n",n, arc);
    int dist[n];
    int k = 0;
    int rows = n;
    int cols = n;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int **cost;
    cost = malloc(rows * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        cost[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
    }

    while (!feof(archive)){
        fscanf (archivo,"%d %d %d", &aux, &aux1, &aux2);
        cost[aux][aux1] = aux2;
        printf("%d %d %d\n", aux, aux1, cost[aux][aux1]);
        aux = 0 ;
        aux1 = 0;
        aux2 = 0;
    }

    printf("\n Enter the Source Node:");
    scanf("%d",&v);

    int h,u,count,w,flag[n],min;

    for(h=0;h < n;h++)
    {
        flag[h]=0;
        dist[h]=cost[v][h];
    }
    count=1;
    while(count&lt;n)
    {
        min=MAX;
        for(w=0;w < n;w++)
        {
            if(dist[w] < min && !flag[w])
            {
                min=dist[w];
                u=w;
            }
        }
        flag[u]=1;
        count++;
        for(w=0; w < n;w++)
        {
            if((dist[u] + cost[u][w] < dist[w]) && !flag[w])
            {
                dist[w] = dist[u] + cost[u][w];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n   Shortest Path from Node %d: ",v);
    printf("\n#################################\n\n");

    for(h=0;h < n;h++)
    {

        printf("Distance to Node:%d is %d\n",(h+1),dist[h]);
    }

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

**TEXTFILE**

```
10 16
1 2  2 
1 4  8
2 4  4
3 4  3
3 5  4
3 8  8
4 5  7
5 6  2
5 7  2
5 8  4
6 7  1
6 9  2
7 8  1
7 10 4
8 10 4
9 10 1
```

Comment: Why are you not checking return values of calls?

Comment: also if u can comment what ur variables such as n, k, etc are that be great

Comment: and can you also paste the contents of TEXTFILE.txt

Comment: If C works similar to C# then you are setting the array value = the instance of aux2.  after doing that you then set that instance to 0.  Which in essence sets cost[aux][aux1] to 0 as well.  In your while loop if you get rid of the three var=0 statements you may find that you get values in your array.

Comment: You may want to initialise the cost array to containg large values, or else any edges that are not in the textfile will be treated as having some random cost (quite possibly 0)

Comment: **ADDED TEXTFILE, i keep getting "[warning] passing arg 3 of dijkstra from incompatible pointer type . thx i'm reading all your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical error in your code is that you have set the values of cost matrix by reading from the file. But other values are zero by default, so you are always getting min as zero. So the pair of of nodes which don't have path between them are considered as the shortest distance. You need to make these cost INFINITE i.e. some very large value.

```
for(i = 0;i < n;i++)  
for(j = 0;j < n;j++)  
{
    if(i!=j)
    {
        if(cost[i][j]==0)
        {
            cost[i][j] = INF;
        }
    }
}
```